# Webpack compile issue - "toString" failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Just tried to compile my webpack project and received the following error:

```
/Users/Chris/Google Drive/AcademyReact/app/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:0



Error: "toString()" failed
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:509:11)
    at utf8BufferToString (/Users/Chris/Google Drive/AcademyReact/app/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:16:16)
    at nextLoader (/Users/Chris/Google Drive/AcademyReact/app/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:274:15)
    at /Users/Chris/Google Drive/AcademyReact/app/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/Chris/Google Drive/AcademyReact/app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/Chris/Google Drive/AcademyReact/app/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:439:3)
```

The project was working absolutely fine before, but for some reason this error started popping up. I haven't made any changes at all to the project - the only changes I have made are to the node.js API server from where the app draws its data.

Can anyone give me a clue as to what is causing this? The error doesn't make any reference to any of my files so struggling to debug. I've searched Google and SO for answers but couldn't find anything relevant - the only reference to a `Buffer.toString()` error I could find related to large file sizes, but I'm not sure that's the issue here.

Thanks!

**Update and solution**

I appear to have found the solution. There was one change that I'd made (which I'd forgotten about) where I'd put a video into one of the folders within the app. Take the video out and the compile appears to work. I suspect it was a file size issue after all!

TBH, I'd planned on moving the videos onto the API Server anyway, so it looks like the problem is solved.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Could you give more information about how you're setting up this project. I see stuff about Google Drive, AcademyReact, etc. Are you using some kind of special learning environment?

Comment: AcademyReact is simply the name of the project - hence the name of the folder. Within the AcademyReact folder there's the `app` folder which contains all of the front end in ReactJS and an `api` folder which has a separate node.js server and MongoDB database. The `api` folder seems to be working fine - accepting requests made using postman and returning the correct info. It's just running the front end in the `app` folder that's throwing the error. The whole project is saved in Google Drive so I can share it between Desktop and Laptop machines.

Comment: I appear to have found the solution. There was one change that I'd made (which I'd forgotten about) where I'd put a video into one of the folders within the app. Take the video out and the compile appears to work. I suspect it was a file size issue after all!

Comment: Please add an answer to your own question explaining what you did to solve it.