# Webpack Agent is failing to run in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, webpack-4

I am trying to run the WebPack command under webpack agent in the Azure DevOps pipeline. But I'm getting the below error. How do I fix this?

```
executing the command: node  "***\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js" --json --config 
../***/webpack.config.js
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]webpack failed
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]webpack failed
(node:9812) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:9812) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:9812) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:9812) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:9812) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:9812) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:9812) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:9812) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:9812) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]webpack failed
##[error]Error: "toString()" failed
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: "toString()" failed
Error: "toString()" failed
at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:495:11)
at spawnSync (child_process.js:443:43)
at Object.execSync (child_process.js:507:13)
at Object.executeWebpackCli [as default] (C:\agent\_work\_tasks\webpack_6752a610-c2f3-11e6-949e-5d3841f133f1\4.2.0\webpackCompiler\WebpackCliExecutor.js:23:28)
at Object.compile (C:\agent\_work\_tasks\webpack_6752a610-c2f3-11e6-949e-5d3841f133f1\4.2.0\webpackCompiler\WebpackCompiler.js:37:46)
at C:\agent\_work\_tasks\webpack_6752a610-c2f3-11e6-949e-5d3841f133f1\4.2.0\index.js:43:46
at next (native)
at C:\agent\_work\_tasks\webpack_6752a610-c2f3-11e6-949e-5d3841f133f1\4.2.0\index.js:7:71
at __awaiter (C:\agent\_work\_tasks\webpack_6752a610-c2f3-11e6-949e-5d3841f133f1\4.2.0\index.js:3:12)
at run (C:\agent\_work\_tasks\webpack_6752a610-c2f3-11e6-949e-5d3841f133f1\4.2.0\index.js:15:12)
```

I am using WebPack Task version - 4.*

The Pipeline is also running npm install before webpack.

Comment: Here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331998/webpack-compile-issue-tostring-failed) you can refer to .

Comment: Large file size may cause this error, you can check if there is a large size file in your folders.

Comment: Actually there is no larger files . but still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your logs, the problem is here:

```
executing the command: node \node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js --json --config webpack.config.js
```

It needs to be:

```
executing the command: node  /node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --json --config webpack-config.js
```

You can change the command path in the webpack configuration section under:
`Advanced/webpack cli location`